# Android Gestures SingleTapConfirmed is slow

Tags: android, android-gesture

I want to trigger two actions when a button is single tapped and double tapped. I've implemented it using GestureDetector as below but there is a significant delay in action when the button is tapped once. I think it waits for the second tap and if there is no second tap then only  single tap is confirmed. How can I resolve this delay as it's very significant to my app.

```
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getApplicationContext(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            //enableShift();
            Log.d("TAGG: ", "Double Tap");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d("TAGG: ", "Single Tap");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I achieved what you need with `onSignleTapUp`. It looks like `SimpleGestureListener` is waiting a bit too long (260ms for me) before triggering `onSingleTapConfirmed`. This is surely for good reasons.

You can tweak your custom `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener()` with a flag `isOnDoubleTapTriggered`.

```kotlin
private var isOnDoubleTapTriggered = false


override fun onSingleTapUp(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    runDelayed(120) { // You can adjust the time here but 120 was the best for me
        if (!isOnDoubleTapTriggered) {
            //enableShift();
        }
        isOnDoubleTapTriggered = false
    }
    return true
}


override fun onDoubleTap(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    isOnDoubleTapTriggered = true
    //enableSmthgElse();
    return true
}
```

Trick explanation :

- Start counting when `onSingleTapUp` is fired
- If `onDoubleTap` has not been triggered before your delay, you can consider single tap is "confirmed"
- Re-Set your flag to `false` (mainly after your second tap up event)

Final tip for you delay:

```kotlin
private fun runDelayed(timeMs: Long, block: () -> Unit) {
    Timer().schedule(
        object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() = block()
        },
        timeMs
    )
}
```